# Error in integrate : evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Tags: r, integration

Try the code below:

```
library(pracma)

f <- function(x) 1

integrate(f,0,1)$value
quad(f,0,1)
```

quad() works correctly but integrate() reports the error message:

> Error in integrate(f, 0, 1) : 
>    evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

What is wrong with this integrate() application? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try:

```
integrate(Vectorize(f),0,1)$value
```

see the manual of `integrate`: `f` should be an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length. `Vectorize` will make `f` a such function that returns an output of the same length as input.

Answer (score 0):

Another illustration of the solution:

```
integrate(function(x) rep(1, length(x)), 0, 1)
```